# Method to get list of AD users using application password

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

In an application, I'm currently using PowerShell and MSOnline module (Connect-MsolService and Get-MsolUser) to get a list of AD users. A global admin provides his username and password and the application is able to get a list of all users under that tenant.

That works fine... As long as the password is not an app password. When an app password is used then the following is what the global admin gets to see:

`Authentication Error: Bad username or password`

My question is: Is there any other method, which uses PowerShell, but doesn't have to, to get the list of users in AD, but which works with app password? I know of Graph API, but that's not a fit for the project right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the AD App and its password(secret) to list the users.

You could use the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azps-2.5.0) powershell module to do that, login with the service principal and list users via [`Get-AzADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azaduser?view=azps-2.5.0). Also, make sure your AD App(service principal) has the admin role like `User administrator` or `Global administrator`.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<AD App Application id>"
$azureTenantId= "<tenant id>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal

Get-AzADUser
```

[image]

**Update**:

Currently, use app password of MFA enabled user to connect MSOL powershell is not supported, for more details see this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/How-to-connect-MSOL-in-powershell-using-App-Password/m-p/221843).

> App passwords are NOT supported, simply use Connect-MsolService without any parameter to trigger the ADAL dialog and complete the 2FA challenge as normal.

Comment: I was actually referring to app password which you create, after you enable MFA for an Office 365 user.

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić I do not understand your meaning, do you mean the password of the AD App? What will the AD App password relate to the user?

Comment: No, I mean an app password, generated for a user. Not an Azure application password. E.g. this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/security-and-compliance/set-up-multi-factor-authentication?view=o365-worldwide#allow-mfa-users-to-create-app-passwords-for-office-client-apps

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić It is not supported to use the app password to connect MSOL powershell,see the link in my update, the guy who is a Microsoft MVP pointed that.

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić Besides, I recommend you to try my way. [Create an AD App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app), give the admin role to it, and use the command above to get users. This is a non-interactive way which is convenient.

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić hi, if my reply is helpful, you could accept it, thanks.

Comment: just did that. Thanks for the help!